# Using Java ObjectMapper to get JSON String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using `writeValueAsString` of the `ObjectMapper` . However, it's giving me a Java String representation so I get:

`{"network_id":5000370004610700049753}`

instead of

`"{\"network_id\":5000370004610700049753}"`

which is failing for other services when deserializing. How do I get this kind of serialization with the `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: did you check this feature ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES

Comment: Well, the first is a string *value* with JSON text, as it should be, so that should be what you'd want. Why do you want the second, i.e. that JSON text encoded as a Java or JSON string?

Comment: The C# service on the other end of the queue fails to deserialize the first one @Andreas

Comment: So the C# code doesn't want plain JSON, but a JSON text encoded as a JSON string? That makes no sense, but doable, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541875/5221149).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the second result, send it through the `ObjectMapper` again.

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("network_id", new BigInteger("5000370004610700049753"));

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String plainJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
System.out.println(plainJson);

String encodedJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(plainJson);
System.out.println(encodedJson);
```

*Output*

```
{"network_id":5000370004610700049753}
"{\"network_id\":5000370004610700049753}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree this is stupid but not sure what's going on on the other end :(